# unable to store variable in Matlab Gui

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I know several variants of this issue have been discussed elsewhere, but I am still unable to solve the problem. Please help.

I have created a function as part of a larger gui, but I am unable to store three data variables (AveX, AveY, AveZ) for later use by guidata(hObject, handles).
What am I doing wrong?

Here is the function:

```
%call all checkbox values
for i = 1:30
checkboxes=get(handles.(sprintf('checkboxAv%d',i)),'value')
Checkboxes(i,1)=checkboxes(1,1);
end

plotdata=handles.plotdata;

[row,col] = find(Checkboxes==1)


num=length(plotdata{1,1}(:,1));
DataY = zeros(num,length(row));%zero matrix

%Average y data
for k=1:length(row)
    DataY(:,k)=plotdata{row(k,1),col(k,1)}(:,4);
end

[m,n] = size(DataY)
if (n==1)
    AveY=DataY'
elseif (n>1)    
    AveY=mean(DataY');
end
AveY=AveY';


%Average X data
for kk=1:length(row)
    DataX(:,kk)=plotdata{row(kk,1),col(kk,1)}(:,1);
end

test=DataX(:,1);
comp=any(bsxfun(@minus,DataX,test),1)
S = sum(comp)
    if (S > 0)
            h=msgbox(['Note! Wavelength index for the selected samples are not identical.'])
    end


[c,r] = size(DataY)
if (r==1)
    AveX=DataX'
elseif (r>1)    
    AveX=mean(DataX');
end
AveX=AveX';


%Average Z data
for kkk=1:length(row)
    DataZ(:,kkk)=plotdata{row(kkk,1),col(kkk,1)}(:,5);
end

[m,n] = size(DataZ)
if (n==1)
    AveZ=DataZ'
elseif (n>1)    
    AveZ=mean(DataZ');
end
AveZ=AveZ';

handles.Aveheader=Aveheader
handles.AveX=AveX;
handles.AveY=AveY;
handles.AveZ=AveZ;
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

And here is the error message:

```
Undefined function or variable 'hObject'.

Error in CDanalyzer>AveragePlotFcn (line 5276)
guidata(hObject, handles);

Error in CDanalyzer>checkboxAv1_Callback (line 5076)
AveragePlotFcn(handles)

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in CDanalyzer (line 17)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)CDanalyzer('checkboxAv1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating UIControl Callback
```

Comment: What is `hObject` supposed to be? Did you pass it into `AveragePlotFcn`?

Comment: Hi Jon. This is where my matlab skills ends. I am a novice in matlab GUI coding. The reason I use guidata(hObject, handles) is that I have used this command line to store data from pushbutton functions. It might be that I am wrong, but at least it worked. But not for my "homemade" function. I just want to store the data somehow.

Comment: So which object are you trying to save with that line? Is there a handle name you made in another function? Maybe try `gcbo` instead of `hObject` if this is a local callback function.

Comment: What I am trying to save is the handles.AveX=AveX; handles.AveY=AveY; and handles.AveZ=AveZ; which are new x,y,z values called in another function where the plotting is happening. I guess this is not an object but a single column data sheet.

Comment: Yes, that's the data but as the documentation says: `guidata(object_handle,data)` stores the variable `data` with the object specified by `object_handle.` So what is the `object_handle` part. Did you try `gcbo`?

Comment: GREAT. gcbo did the trick. Thanks a lot. One last question. Could you please tell me what the difference is between the gcbo and hobject is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`guidata(object_handle,data)` stores the variable `data` with the object specified by `object_handle`" you need to specify the `object_handle`. Currently `hObject` is undefined in this local function.

Use [gcbo](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcbo.html) instead, which "returns the handle of the graphics object whose callback is executing":

```
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

becomes

```
guidata(gcbo, handles);
```

---

Alternatively, add `hObject` as an input to the function `AveragePlotFcn`. So:

```
function AveragePlotFcn(hObject,~)
...
end
```